# sendkeys during the apearance of dialogbox

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I need to use sendkeys during the appearance of `ShowSaveAsDialog` in VB.2010 webbrowser control. But it seemed that it's not functioning because it waits first for the dialog to be closed before it activates.

Here is my code:

```
WebBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog()
Timer1.Enabled = True
```

*in the timer event

```
SendKeys.Send("AAAAAA")<br>
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")<br>
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")<br>
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")<br>
Timer1.Enabled = False
```

I need to send the "AAAAAAA" to the file name but its not working...

Comment: This fits the category of "what else could you do if this actually works?"  This would of course be a major security leak, allowing malware to arbitrary save any file to the user's machine just by inducing the user to visit a web site.  Long distance killer poke.  Of course it doesn't work.

Comment: i want to download a webpage displayed in the webbrowser using showsaveasdialog but i want to download it automatically without interaction with the user... i want to send the file name and click the save button in the dialog...

Comment: Yes, that was already obvious.  What doesn't appear to be obvious to you is how this could be abused so is therefore disabled.  Just google "webbrowser save page", the 4th hit points to a FAQ on the MSDN forums that looks good.