# Save image with ShowSaveAsDialog

Tags: c#, image, download

I have a web browser on which I navigate to the image URL that I want to download and then I show a dialog to save with ShowSaveAsDialog. I would like to send keys to this dialog so it will automatically register. Here is what I've done :

```
this.webBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog();
SendKeys.SendWait("aaaaaa");
SendKeys.SendWait("{tab}");
SendKeys.SendWait("{tab}");
SendKeys.SendWait("{enter}");
```

It seems that it does nothing and the dialog stays opened.

EDIT : No solutions found

Comment: why don't you use `HttpClient`

Comment: Any chance `ShowSaveAsDialog()` blocks your UI thread, causing `SendKeys.SendWait()` to never run?

Comment: I'm using this solution because from what I've seen, HttpClient needs you to be logged in (I have to be logged in to get the image) and i haven't succeeded doing it so when the user is connected with the web browser, i navigate to the image url and call 'ShowSaveAsDialog'.
To answer to CodeCaster, i think it might be something like this, i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I've found this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924391/sendkeys-during-the-apearance-of-dialogbox
It seems that I just can't SendKeys ...

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924391/sendkeys-during-the-apearance-of-dialogbox